# How can I visit NodePort service in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

This is my Service yaml. When create the svc on GKE.I don't know how can I visit the svc.I can't find a external ip for visiting the svc. How can I visit this svc in standard flow. Is it need to create an ingress?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: dev
  name: ui-svc
  labels:
    targetEnv: dev
    app: ui-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: ui
    targetEnv: dev
  ports:
    - name: ui
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30080
  type: NodePort
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't use a [private cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/private-cluster-concept) where nodes don't have public IP addresses, you can access your `NodePort` services using any node's public IP address.

What you can see in `Services & Ingresses` section in the `Endpoints` column, it's an internal, cluster ip address of your `NodePort` service.

If you want to know what are public IP addresses of your **GKE nodes**, please go to **Compute Engine** > **VM instances**:

[image]

You will see the list of all your **Compute Engine VMs** which also includes your **GKE nodes**. Note the IP address in `External IP` column. You should use it along with port number which you may check in your `NodePort` service details. Simply click on it's name `"ui-svc"` to see the details. At the very bottom of the page you should see `ports` section which may look as follows:

[image]

So in my case I should use `<any_node's_public_ip_address>:31251`.

One more important thing. Don't forget to allow traffic to this port on **Firewall** as by default it is blocked. So you need to explicitly allow traffic to your nodes e.g. on `31251` port to be able to access it from public internet. Simply go to **VPC Network** > **Firewall** and set the apropriate rule:

[image]

#### UPDATE:

If you created an [Autopilot Cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview), by default it is a public one, which means its nodes have public IP addresses:

[image]

If during the cluster creation you've selected a second option i.e. `"Private cluster"`, your nodes won't have public IPs by design and you won't be able to access your `NodePort` service on any public IP. So the only option that remains in such scenario is exposing your workload via `LoadBalancer` service or `Ingress`, where a single public IP endpoint is created for you, so you can access your workload externally.

However if you've chosen the default option i.e. `"Public cluster"`, you can use your node's public IP's to access your `NodePort` service in the very same way as if you used a Standard (non-autopilot) cluster.

Of course in autopilot mode you won't see your nodes as compute engine VMs in your GCP console, but you can still get their public IPs by running:

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide
```

They will be shown in `EXTERNAL-IP` column.

To connect to your cluster simply click on 3 dots you can see to the right of the cluster name (`"Kubernetes Engine"` > `"Clusters"`) > click `"Connect"` > click `"RUN IN CLOUD SHELL"`.

Since you don't know what network tags have been assigned to your GKE auto-pilot nodes (if any) as you don't manage them and they are not shown in your GCP console, you won't be able to use specified network tags when defining a firewall rule to allow access to your `NodePort` service port e.g. `30543` and you would have to choose the option `"All instances in the network"` instead:

[image]

Comment: Thank you . But I can't see my k8snode at Compute Engine > VM instances. Cause I am in a Autopilot model. Is thers  an official recommanded way to expose servcies in any model?

Comment: @PengboWu, as you didn't mention in your question that you use **Autopilot mode** I assumed it is a standard **GKE** cluster. I have already updated my answer. You'll find all the necessary detail in **UPDATE** section :)